# $\mathbb Q$ dense in $[0,1]$? Or a subset of $\mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis

I have read the proofs that $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R$ but I am a little uncomfortable claiming $\mathbb Q$ is dense in a subset if $\mathbb R$.  Any help?

Comment: Are you uncomfortable claiming that $[0, 1] \cap \mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $[0, 1]$? Other than that, I agree that when we say "$S$ is dense in $T$", it is presupposed that $S$ is a subset of $T$. I would not, for example, say that the rationals are dense in the irrationals.

Comment: I think that “$\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $[0, 1]$” is just a shortcut for “$\mathbb{Q} ∩ [0, 1]$ is dense in $[0, 1]$”. So under this interpretation the claim is true. Note that rationals are not dense in irrationals even with this interpretation.

Comment: @user43208 that is exactly what I am uncomfortable with.

Comment: The more I think about it I think it is indeed true.  Thank you everyone.

Comment: $\mathbb Q$ is not dense in any subset of $\mathbb R$.  Particularly $\mathbb Q$ (or more exactly $\mathbb Q\cap A$) is not dense in $A=\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$.